# How to put text outside of plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, plot-annotations

I am plotting two time series and computing varies indices for them.

How to write these indices for these plots outside the plot using `annotation` or `text` in python?

Below is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

obs_graph=plt.plot(obs_df['cms'], '-r', label='Observed')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.hold(True)
sim_graph=plt.plot(sim_df['cms'], '-g', label="Simulated")
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.ylabel('Daily Discharge (m^3/s)')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.title('Observed vs Simulated Daily Discharge')
textstr = 'NSE=%.2f\nRMSE=%.2f\n'%(NSE, RMSE)
# print textstr
plt.text(2000, 2000, textstr, fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I want to print `teststr` outside the plots. Here is the current plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Next time, please provide some [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code (i.e., don't reference a DataFrame that only you have access to).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It's probably best to define the position in figure coordinates instead of data coordinates as you'd probably not want the text to change its position when changing the data.

Using figure coordinates can be done either by specifying the figure transform (`fig.transFigure`)

```
plt.text(0.02, 0.5, textstr, fontsize=14, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

or by using the `text` method of the figure instead of that of the axes.

```
plt.gcf().text(0.02, 0.5, textstr, fontsize=14)
```

In both cases the coordinates to place the text are in figure coordinates, where `(0,0)` is the bottom left and `(1,1)` is the top right of the figure.

At the end you still may want to provide some extra space for the text to fit next to the axes, using `plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.3)` or so.

Comment: I am wondering, there is no subplot, so why do you use a subplot method ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin There is a single subplot present.

Comment: a plot is a subplot ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin Any axes that is automatically created via `plt.plot` or other convenience functions like `plt.gca`, `plt.subplot(s)`, `plt.gcf().add_subplot` is a subplot.

Comment: adding for great answer; for axes objects use ```transAxes``` instead of ```transFigure```

Comment: `plt.text(0, -0.1, 'test', fontsize=14, transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)` This will not show text outside of the figure.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the text is there but it lies outside of the figure boundary.
Use [`subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) to make room for the text:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

textstr = 'NSE=%.2f\nRMSE=%.2f\n'%(1, 2)
plt.xlim(2002, 2008)
plt.ylim(0, 4500)
# print textstr
plt.text(2000, 2000, textstr, fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I could not see the text even after using 'subplots_adjust()'. Do I need to define `xlim` and `ylim`?

Comment: Nope, i used those to get the same axis range without your data. Do you see the text if you run my example? Maybe different versions of Matplotlib? I use version 1.5.2 (on Python 3, but that should be irrelevant). You can also play with different values of `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` - maybe the text is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried top,left,bottom and right, but could not find the text. I am using Python 2.7.11 and matplotlib version 1.5.1. Yes I can see the text in your example. I have uploaded my file in edit, could you lease check them with my code.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to Python until after the weekend. I suggest you start with a working example and add your stuff piece by piece until it stops working. Then fix that part :)

Comment: Thanks buddy, I did it. Eventually :)

Comment: Good to hear! You could share your solution as another answer to help others who run into the same problem in the future.

Comment: I could not print the textscr outside the plot, but could placed it inside the plot using `plt.figtext(0.15,0.58, textstr, fontsize=14, bbox=dict(facecolor='wheat', alpha=0.5))`

Comment: @dsbisht Please provide your solution so others can benefit

Answer (score 4):

According to Matplotlib version 3.3.4 documentation, you can use the [figtext method](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html#matplotlib-pyplot-figtext):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figtext(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)
```

or in your case

```
plt.figtext(0.02, 0.5, textstr, fontsize=14)
```

It seems to give the same result as one of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42439154/5722359) by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, i.e. :

```
plt.gcf().text(0.02, 0.5, textstr, fontsize=14)
```

I have used both commands with Matplobib version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `bbox`

If you want the box to be **outside** the plot, and not to be cropped when saving the figure, you have to use `bbox`. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(8, 4))
x = np.random.normal(loc=15.0, scale=2.0, size=10000)
mu = np.mean(x)
sigma = np.std(x)

my_text = '- Estimated quantities -\n'
my_text += fr'$\mu=${mu:.3f}' + '\n' + fr'$\sigma=${sigma:.3f}'

ax.hist(x, bins=100)
props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.15)  # bbox features
ax.text(1.03, 0.98, my_text, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, verticalalignment='top', bbox=props)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram with box outside frame]

More details here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/gallery/recipes/placing_text_boxes.html