# how to convert 168 data points to hourly plot data for weekdays

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame as:

[image]

and I can plot this data as :

[image]

how can I make x axis of this plot like the following plot:

[image]

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
ax1.set(xlabel='hours in a week', ylabel='occupancy ratio(0-1)')
ax1.plot(HoursOfWeek.values, color='g')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plotting the graph, you can edit the x-ticks. Documentation:
[plt.xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

For the markers,

```
plt.xticks(np.r_[0:15]*7, ['00','12']*7+['00'])
```

For the x-axis labels, plt.xlabel or plt.text should do the job.
Documentation: [plt.xlabel](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)

I suggest you use this method to write the x-label:
[How to put text outside python plots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42435446/how-to-put-text-outside-python-plots)(ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer)